# Change value of input field - trigger() and change() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onchange

I want to change the value of an input field with javascript - WITH BROWSER CONSOLE.

I tried

`$('input[name="anumber"]').val('200').change();`

and

`$('input[name="anumber"]').val('200').trigger('change');`

So the value changes for half a second to 200 but then changes again back to the original number. Is the website preventing my input and how can I still input something without typing on my keyboard?

Any Help?

Comment: should be working... pls create a [minimal and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The website you are trying to use that code on probable doesn't have the jQuery library active.